# Qt parse an array of objects JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt, parsing

I have this following JSON request(only a snippet of it) and I am trying to parse the temperatureHigh in data[{}].  I can't figure out how to parse an array of objects thats inside an object.  Im using Qt.

```
{    
    "latitude":xxx,
    “longitude":xxx,
    “timezone":"America/New_York",
    “currently":{
    "time":1552765335,
    “summary":"Clear",
    “icon":"clear-day",
    “nearestStormDistance":4,
    “nearestStormBearing":268,
    “precipIntensity":0,
    “precipProbability":0,
    “temperature":48.32,
    “apparentTemperature":43.25,
    “dewPoint":20.91,
    “humidity":0.33,
    “pressure":1014.29,
    “windSpeed":12.22,
    “windGust":20.11,
    “windBearing":310,
    “cloudCover":0.04,
    “uvIndex":3,
    “visibility":9.64,
    “ozone":317.85
    },
    “daily":{
        "summary":"No precipitation throughout the week, with high temperatures falling to 43°F on Tuesday.",
        “icon":"clear-day",
        “data":[{
            "time":1552708800,
            “summary":"Partly cloudy until afternoon.",
            “icon":"partly-cloudy-day",
            “sunriseTime":1552734266,
            “sunsetTime":1552777293,
            “moonPhase":0.34,
            “precipIntensity":0.0007,
            “precipIntensityMax":0.0101,
            “precipIntensityMaxTime":1552708800,
            “precipProbability":0.35,
            “precipType":"rain",
            “temperatureHigh":48.89,
            “temperatureHighTime":1552759200,
            “temperatureLow":31.84,
            “temperatureLowTime":1552820400,
            “apparentTemperatureHigh":43.85,
            “apparentTemperatureHighTime":1552762800,
            “apparentTemperatureLow":22.64,
            “apparentTemperatureLowTime":1552820400,
            “dewPoint":29.06,
            “humidity":0.52,
```

So far this is what I have

```
QJsonParseError jError;
QJsonDocument test = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data, &jError);

QVariantMap qVar1 = jObj.value("daily").toVariant().toMap();
```

Comment: The full JSON request can be seen at https://api.darksky.net/forecast/8fd6289f02cec9a891081d5e0ac5675c/41.1412,-73.2638?exclude=minutely,alerts,flags,hourly

Comment: Do you just need to use qVar1["temperatureHigh"].toDouble()?

Comment: @Ian4264 No that doesn't work.  qVar1 only sees summary, icon, and data

Comment: Ah yes, didn't spot the brackets. I think you need something like qVar1["data"].toArray().front() ["temperatureHigh"]

Comment: Be careful with your quotation marks: `“` is different from `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the minimal JSON sample I worked with:

```
{
    "humidity": 0.33,
    "pressure": 1014.29,
    "daily": {
        "data": [
            {
                "temperatureHigh": 48.89,
                "temperatureLow": 31.84
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Assuming that you've already read or stored your JSON into a `QByteArray` instance called `json`:

```
QJsonParseError err;
auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json, &err);           // parse the json
if (err.error != QJsonParseError::NoError)
    qDebug() << err.errorString();

QJsonObject obj = doc.object();                                  // get the object
qDebug() << "obj:" << obj;

QJsonObject daily = obj.value("daily").toObject();               // get the daily value as an object     
qDebug() << "daily:" << daily;

QJsonArray data = daily.value("data").toArray();                // get the data value as an array    
qDebug() << "data:" << data;

QJsonObject first = data[0].toObject();                          // get the first value as an object    
qDebug() << "first:" << first;

double temperatureHigh = first.value("temperatureHigh").toDouble(); // get the temperatureHigh value    
qDebug() << "temperatureHigh:" << temperatureHigh;
```

Output:

```
obj: QJsonObject({"daily":{"data":[{"temperatureHigh":48.89,"temperatureLow":31.84}]},"humidity":0.33,"pressure":1014.29})
daily: QJsonObject({"data":[{"temperatureHigh":48.89,"temperatureLow":31.84}]})
data: QJsonArray([{"temperatureHigh":48.89,"temperatureLow":31.84}])
first: QJsonObject({"temperatureHigh":48.89,"temperatureLow":31.84})
temperatureHigh: 48.89
```

In one line:

```
auto temperatureHigh = doc.object().value("daily").toObject().value("data").toArray()[0].toObject().value("temperatureHigh");
```

Some variants you might like to opt for (by taking advantage of [`QJsonValue::operator[]` overloads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#operator-5b-5d)):

```
auto temperatureHigh = doc.object().value("daily")["data"][0].toObject()["temperatureHigh"];

----

const auto obj = doc.object();    // obj must be const to call the appropriate overload that returns QJsonValue   
auto temperatureHigh = obj["daily"]["data"][0]["temperatureHigh"];
```

Really, the only classes and types you should be conscious of while traversing your JSON are [`QJsonObject`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html), [`QJsonArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html), and [`QJsonValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html). (There's not really any need to use to `QVariant` or `QVariantMap`.) Read the docs, write more code, and you'll get used to it. :-)